# How to add a CSS Style Class to a QWidget

Tags: c++, css, qt, qwidget, qtstylesheets

In JavaFx I can easily add a CSS style class as follows:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 500, 400);
scene.getStylesheets().add("path/stylesheet.css");

......

Label label = new Label("Cool Looking Styled Label");
label.getStyleClass().add("my-label-style");
```

**css**

```
.my-label-style {
    -fx-font: 16px "Serif";
    -fx-padding: 10;
    -fx-background-color: #CCFF99;
}
```

How can I go about adding a style class to a **QWidget**, `QLabel`, for example?

Comment: I use `Label->setStyleSheet("style sheet goes here");` then   `Label->ensurePolished();` then `Label->update();`

Answer (score 5):

```
label->setProperty("class", "my-label-style");
```

Then in a CSS you can call it normally by:

```
.my-label-style {
  [..]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The method is in the QWidget base class; it's QWidget::setStyleSheet.

Answer (score 0):

you have two ways to do that

> coding

- widget.setStyleSheet("css code");

> Form ui

- right click on the widget
- select change stylesheet
- a dialog box appears where you need to write css codes

but all css code are not supported ,you need to see documentation of stylesheet